# ¿como admitir solo números enteros en c++?

Tags: c++

quiero validar si el dato que me da el usuario es entero y en caso contrario que mande un mensaje de que no es valor correcto

Este es mi código hasta el momento

```
int i,j,n1,n2,n3,aux;
cout<<"\n\t********************************************************************"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n\t ";
cout<<"\n\t\t\t\tBIENVENIDO!!!!!"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n\t ";
cout<<"\n\t********************************************************************"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\tEste programa ordena de mayor a menor"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n\tNOTAS:"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\t1- Solo se aceptan valores positivos enteros entre 1 y 9"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\t2- Valores mayores o menores no son validos"<<endl;
cout<<"\n\t\tIngrese el primer numero: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin>>n1;

cout<<"\n\t\tIngrese el segundo numero: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin>>n2;

cout<<"\n\t\tIngrese el tercer numero: ";
fflush(stdin);
cin>>n3;

cout<<"\n";
for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=n1-i;j++)
    cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    cout<<"*";

    cout<<"\n";

}
    cout<<"("<<n1<<")"<<endl;

cout<<"\n";
for(i=1;i<=n2;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=n2-i;j++)
    cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    cout<<"*";

    cout<<"\n";

}
    cout<<"("<<n2<<")"<<endl;

    cout<<"\n";
for(i=1;i<=n3;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=n3-i;j++)
    cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    cout<<"*";

    cout<<"\n";

}
    cout<<"("<<n3<<")"<<endl;

    if(n1<n2) 
        { 
            aux=n2; 
            n2=n1; 
            n1=aux; 
        }    

    if(n2<n3) 
        { 
            aux=n2; 
            n2=n3; 
            n3=aux; 
        } 

    if(n1<n2) 
        {    
            aux=n1; 
            n1=n2; 
            n2=aux; 
        } 
    cout<<"\n***********************************************************************************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n Los Datos ordenados descendentemente son:";

        cout<<"\n\n";
for(i=1;i<=n1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=n1-i;j++)
    cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    cout<<"*";

    cout<<"\n";

}
    cout<<"("<<n1<<")"<<endl;

cout<<"\n";
for(i=1;i<=n2;i++){
    cout<<"\t ";
    for(j=1;j<=n2-i;j++)
    cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    cout<<"*";

    cout<<"\n";

}
    cout<<"\t\t("<<n2<<")"<<endl;

    cout<<"\n";
for(i=1;i<=n3;i++){
    cout<<"\t\t ";
    for(j=1;j<=n3-i;j++)
    cout<<" ";
    for(j=1;j<=2*i-1;j++)
    cout<<"*";

    cout<<"\n";

}
    cout<<"\t\t\t("<<n3<<")"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\tProgramo: Carrillo Paredes Alfonso Eduardo"<<endl;
cout<<"\n***********************************************************************************************************"<<endl;
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: @Alfabravo la pregunta está al inicio, pregunté que como puedo hacer para admitir solo números enteros

Comment: Umm, probaste algo para hacer que admita enteros? Salió algún error al probarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ ofrece una herramienta de lectura (con formato) de la consola, son los flujos de datos ([`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)) y su operador de extracción ([`operator >>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)), por lo tanto puedes usar una variable entera y extraer datos de la consola a dicha variable:

```
int i;
std::cin >> i;
```

El problema es que leerá igualmente tanto un número entero como `3` como un número con decimales como `3.14`, y en ambos casos leerá `3`. Para esquivar este problema lee en un número con decimales y tras leerlo comprueba si tiene decimales:

```
double d;
std::cin >> d;

if (std::fmod(d, 1.) > .0)
    std::cout << "Error: Quiero un entero!\n");
```

Una vez sabes que no tiene decimales, puedes tratarlo como entero, por ejemplo: con una conversión:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(d);
```

Para facilitar las cosas, podrías escribir una función:

```
int lee_un_entero()
{
    bool decimales = true;

    do
    {
        double d;
        std::cin >> d;

        if ((decimales = (std::fmod(d, 1.) > .0))
            std::cout << "Error: Quiero un entero!\n");
    } while (decimales);

    return static_cast<int>(d);
}
```

Comment: cuando pongo la funcion que me diste, no me corre, dice [Error] 'fmod' is not a member of 'std', [Error] expected ')' before 'std', [Error] 'd' was not declared in this scope, perdon si no entiendo algo, la verdad no he trabajado con funciones y no se como usarlas muy bien

Comment: `std::fmod` pertenece a la cabecera [`<cmath>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath), necesitas incluirla.

Answer (score 1):

Como te ha comentado @Paula_plus_plus, `cin` tiene sobrecargado el operador `>>`. Si usas la sobrecarga para tipos enteros:

```
int var:
std::cin >> var;
```

... y el usuario introduce una cadena, por ejemplo "abcd", `cin` se bloqueará y se activará el flag de error. Para realizar futuras lecturas es necesario desbloquear `cin` reseteando el flag de error.

Podemos aprovechar esta característica para detectar cuando el usuario ha introducido algo que no es un número:

```
#include <limits> // para std::numeric_limits

while( true )
{
  int var;
  std::cin >> var;

  if( std::cin.fail() )
  {
    std::cout >> "ERROR: Introduce un numero\n";
    std::cin.clear();                                      // Reseteamos el flag de error
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n'); // Descartamos los caracteres erroneos del buffer de entrada
  }
}

std::cout << var;
```

Ahora bien, esto puede dar resultados extraños si, por ejemplo, se introduce un número seguido de caracteres no numéricos:

```
123ABCD
```

En este caso no saldrá el mensaje... ¿Qué ha sucedido? Pasa que `cin` solo se queja si **el primer caracter no es numérico**. Si no es el caso, `cin` empezará a leer el número y parará cuando se encuentre con un caracter no numérico... En el caso anterior el programa imprimirá `123` y dejará `ABCD` en el buffer de entrada... se puede ver con este otro ejemplo:

```
int numero;
std::string cadena;

std::cin >> numero >> cadena;
std::cout << "Numero: " << numero << '\n'
          << "Cadena: " << cadena << '\n';
```

Ante esta situación tenemos dos opciones... o la intentamos detectar y le mostramos un mensaje al usuario o bien nos quedamos con la parte entera y descartamos lo demás. Lo más sencillo es optar por la segunda opción:

```
int var;
std::cin >> var;

if( std::cin.fail() )
{
  std::cout << "ERROR"\n;
  std::cin.clear();
}
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
```

... ya que la primera nos obliga a leer la entrada del usuario línea a línea en modo cadena de texto y comprobar si dicha línea cumple o no con nuestros requisitos:

```
std::string linea;
int var = 0;
std::getline(std::cin,linea);
bool ok = std::all_of(linea.begin(),linea.end(),::isdigit);
if( !ok )
  std::cout << "ERROR\n";
else
{
  var = std::stoi(linea);
  std::cout << var << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la operación `%`.

Por ejemplo `(con n1)`

```
si (n1%1) != 0 entonces n1 no es entero.
si (n1%1)==0 entonces es entero
```

También puedes hacer esto que se asegura que la entrada, además de ser un número también es entera.

```
int x ;
cin >> x;
If (cin.fail ()) 
{
// no es un número entero
}
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Como te han contestado ya, la opción más facil es realizar el módulo del número que tienes en la variable.

Otra opción sería pasar el numero a entero:
[stackOverFlow ENG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27716799/c-alternative-to-integer-parseint-and-string-valueof)

Aquí tienes algunos operadores de C y C++, ten cuidado por que no todos los implementados en C++ se pueden utilizar en C: [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:Operadores_de_C_y_C%2B%2B)