# ¿Cómo puedo validar la entrada de un dato para una variable double que sea diferente de un conjunto vacío c++?

Tags: c++11, dev-c++

Básicamente mi duda es que cuando le pida al usuario ingresar un numero si este solo le da enter o pone un espacio y le da enter, le vuelva a decir que digite de nuevo el número, logré hacer algo similar pero con una variable string utilizando una funcion .empty()

```
string nombres;
cout << "Ingrese los nombres del empleado:" << endl;
        getline(cin,nombres);
        //la funcion .empty detecta si esta vacio
        while (nombres.empty()) 
        {
            cout << "*Rellene el campo*, Ingrese los nombres del empleado:" << endl;
            getline(cin,nombres);
        }
```

Pero esa función empty(), solo se encuentra disponible con variables string.

En pocas palabras me gustaría hacer algo así como el ejemplo que puse pero con variables double, mas especifico quiero que cuando se ingrese el salario del empleado no le permita ingresar conjunto vacíos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿como admitir solo números enteros en c++?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154275/como-admitir-solo-n%c3%bameros-enteros-en-c)

Answer (score 0):

Hay que tener en cuenta que `getline` solo lee una string. Por lo que si deseas leer un entero, tendrás que pasar de string a integer.

Puedes aprovecharlo y hacer `.empty()` de esa string al igual que haces con nombres:

```
int main() {
  string numero;
  cout << "Ingrese un numero:" << endl;
  getline(cin,numero);
  //la funcion .empty detecta si esta vacio
  while (numero.empty()) 
  {
      cout << "*Rellene el campo*, Ingrese un numero:" << endl;
      getline(cin,numero);
  }
}
```